# Получить локальный php файл как текст не исполняя его как код

Tags: php

Нужно получить php файл как текст, естественно не выполняя код в самом файле, то есть только прочитать его.

Делаю так, но не выходит

```
$txt = fopen('functions.php', 'r');
echo $txt;
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` вам в помощь

Comment: @Naumov, пробовал, он выдаёт исполненное содержимое, а не сам тест php файла

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("functions.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("functions.php"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Так-же стоит напомнить что содержимое файла (в примере выше) выводится напрямую в браузер и есть вероятность ничего не увидеть на странице, т.к. php файлы обычно начинаются с символа открытия тега `<?php` что может быть расценено как html тег и не будет отображено на странице. Однако посмотрев исходный код страницы  вы точно увидите полное содержимое указанного файла.

Comment: чтобы теги не работали, нужно обернуть выводимый текст в htmlspecialchars()